# How to reuse the same str_replace-like function pathauto is configured to?

Tags: 7, forms, path-aliases

Use case: Custom module to alter `CONTENTTYPE_node_forms` to hide some of many entity reference options when adding/editing a node. Then via a custom validate I set $`form_state['values']['path']['pathauto'] = 0` and want to set the `$form_state['values']['path']['alias']` depending on the parent item of the chosen entity reference since unfortunately Pathauto doesn't provide tokens for that. Finally the alias should look like that: `parent-entity/entity/$form_state['input']['title']`.

I builded that pattern by hand now and I'm asking me after I couldn't find anything, if I also have to rebuild the whole `str_replace`/`preg_replace` pattern of Pathauto or if there's a way to reuse the same pattern Pathauto is using for replacing spaces, special characters etc.?

Or is there maybe any other intelligent alternative to set a path alias pattern like that?

Comment: Can't quite understand what you're asking, but on the off-chance you're referring to `_pathauto_clean_string()`, then yes, you can re-use that with your custom logic

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!